# Height set to 7rem, but shrinks when the viewport shrinks?

Tags: html, css

[The link buttons in this demo](https://superflycss.github.io/component-site/deploy/) are set to a height of 7 rem.

```
   <a class="Button
             u-flex-shrink0
             u-flex-grow1
             u-height7rem
             href="Site" >Site</a>
   <a class="Button
             u-flex-shrink0
             u-flex-grow1
             u-height7rem" href="Site--centered" >Site--centered</a>
```

This is an approximation of the code contained in the link:

```html
    <nav style="display: flex; align-items: stretch; ">
       <a style="flex-shrink: 0; flex: 1 1 0%; display: inline-flex; height: 7rem; background-color: gray;" href="Site" >Site</a>
       <a style="flex-shrink: 0; flex: 1 1 0%; display: inline-flex; height: 7rem; background-color: gray;" href="Site">Site--centered</a>       
    </nav>
```

If the viewport is shrunk, the height of the buttons also gets smaller.  I'm trying to figure out why, because there is height constraint on the container element.

If I remove `flex: 1 1 0%;` then the buttons will have 7rem as height, so I'm trying to understand why `flex: 1 1 0%;` overrides the height.

Having looked at it more closely it seems flex-basis 0% overrides the height setting ...but only when the button content wraps ... So I'm trying to understand this dynamic better ...

[image]

Comment: second question without MCVE .. you need to share code here so we can give you answers

Comment: no, a link can die or can be edited to no more show the initial issue

Comment: How about we compromise - If the answer does not contain enough information to deduce the full context of the question (The image paint a pretty good context) I'll follow up with MVCE code?

Comment: I am not talking about *now* .. I can easily give you an answer and it's about .u-flex-grow1 that is applying flex-basis:100%. Now think about the future: your link will be dead and we have no idea about the CSS you are applying because you only shared a html code so your question will become useless, it will get closed, downvoted, deleted.

Comment: after 6years and 500+ questions you should know that image of code is a very bad thing.

Comment: You have a point - OK - I'll make sure to throw in an MVCE.

Comment: How does it look?

Comment: I added minimal markup (Rendering not sexy) and explained that the flex: 1 1 0%;  part causes the undesired override effect.  If the answer now explains then future readers have full context.

Comment: You still haven't provided the CSS.

Comment: Because this is what I'm wondering about: flex: 1 1 0%;  ... Why does that cause the shrinkage in height ... the CSS is in the style attribute on the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working right in the dev tools by adding the following to your class ".u-height7rem"

```
min-height: 7rem;
```